# How to write a list of list into excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

How to write a list of list into excel using python 3?

```
new_list = [["first", "second"], ["third", "fourth"]]
with open("file_name.csv", 'w') as f:
    fc = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
fc.writerows(new_list)
```

I can write this list into `csv` file but How canI want to write in excel file?

Comment: Have a look at `openpyxl` or `xlwings` to write into a file with `xl/xls` format. But, you should be able to open your csv file in Excel right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html):

```
import xlsxwriter

new_list = [['first', 'second'], ['third', 'four'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for row_num, data in enumerate(new_list):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 39):

You can use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

```python
import pandas as pd

new_list = [["first", "second"], ["third", "four"], ["five", "six"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(new_list)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='welcome', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Related documentation:

- [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library to write and read data in this library the function [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel(..)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel) will make you able to directly write to excel files for all this you may need to define [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) for this work here is a [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python) on pandas-dataframe by dataCamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with openpyxl library.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

new_list = [["first", "second"], ["third", "fourth"]]

wb = Workbook() # creates a workbook object.
ws = wb.active # creates a worksheet object.

for row in new_list:
    ws.append(row) # adds values to cells, each list is a new row.

    
wb.save('File_Name.xlsx') # save to excel file.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyexcel

# Get the data
new_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

# Save the array to a file
pyexcel.save_as(array=new_list, dest_file_name="array_data.xls")


# Retrieve the records of the file
# records = pyexcel.get_records(file_name="test.xls")

# Get an array from the data
# my_array = pyexcel.get_array(file_name="test.xls")

# Get your data in a dictionary of 2D arrays
# 2d_array_dictionary = pyexcel.get_book_dict(file_name="test.xls")

# The data
# 2d_array_dictionary = {'Sheet 1': [
                               ['ID', 'AGE', 'SCORE']
                               [1, 22, 5],
                               [2, 15, 6],
                               [3, 28, 9]
                              ],
                   'Sheet 2': [
                                ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                                [1, 2, 3],
                                [4, 5, 6]
                                [7, 8, 9]
                              ],
                   'Sheet 3': [
                                ['M', 'N', 'O', 'P'],
                                [10, 11, 12, 13],
                                [14, 15, 16, 17]
                                [18, 19, 20, 21]
                               ]}

  # Save the data to a file                        
  # pyexcel.save_book_as(bookdict=2d_array_dictionary, dest_file_name="2d_array_data.xls")
```

Answer (score -3):

I think the most convenient way is to use Series in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

new_list =['whatever']
pd.Series(new_list)
new_list.to_excel('aFileName.xlsx')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'